# How to recover an Android phone if the Launcher has been mistakenly quarantined?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, launcher, lenovo

I am using an Android phone with Root access. I have an app called [App Quarantine ROOT/FREEZE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.appquarantine&hl=en), which can freeze or quarantine unwanted apps in Android. I mistakenly use this app to quarantine the Launcher.

As soon as I quarantine the Launcher, the Android desktop becomes black. When I try to reboot, it stuck at the boot up screen with logo.

How to recover an Android phone if the Launcher has been mistakenly quarantined? How to recover the Launcher?

Comment: Can you get to recovery? You can reset your phone from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some phone models have an emergency factory reset button at the back(inside the back cover) of the phone. It looks like a pinhole. Try inserting a pin there. I hope it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. but I could access the notification drawer. and I had a battery booster installed. So , I clicked it and clicked the rating button. It went directly to Google play and find the app's page and open it. You can unfreeze it then.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem but on TV (mistakenly disable default launcher)
So here what I did.

As My TV was already connected to Wifi but was stuck at "Android" black screen.

So just grabbed my phone

Logged in play store with same account I was using on TV using browser.

Searched launcher

Clicked on install

Selected device > android  TV

& Voila in next 5 secs launcher got Installed in my tv &  then i enabled default launcher.

Everything was working fine.