# What happens if you manually remove every launcher from your phone?

Tags: launcher

Someone on G+ is asking for help, claiming they accidentally uninstalled every launcher from their phone. He said his phone is stuck at the "company logo" when he turns his phone on (sounds like a brick to me).

He says his phone is rooted, so it's possible.

I've never done anything this dumb before (and don't plan to), so I can't verify what's going on.

If you uninstall every launcher from your Android phone, what happens when you turn it on? Will it actually refuse to boot properly if you don't have a launcher installed?

Comment: I don't think you can't remove the default launcher...He must have messed something else up...

Comment: You probably could. You can remove built in apps if you're rooted, so unless they have "special protection" on the default launcher, it should be possible.

Comment: This can happen: [Deleted my only Launcher and APK - Black Screen. Please help!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124441) and so as this: [How to recover an Android phone if the Launcher has been mistakenly quarantined?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/92549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launcher is an app which gives interface between user and other apps.We can delete default launcher by root access.If default launcher is deleted (Assuming no other launcher is installed on phone), then OS will work but we can't access any other apps from phone and it is looks like crashed phone.

So when you reboot without a launcher it will not go to any home page because there is no launcher at all. 
So

```
1> It may show a blank screen 
2> It may show company symbol with sound 
3> Some times it shows "system stopped working" message
```

In this situation if you factory reset the phone (using boot loader) then also you will not able to get the launcher because the default app in the ROM is deleted.

To solve this you have to install ROM again you can also take necessary data backup(Using custom recovery).

You can also switch on phone and install launcher from Play Store using laptop/computer.Go to [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) in PC and hit install on any launcher and it will install on phone.(You have to connect your phone to internet and signed in from same Google account)

You can install launcher app using a zip file. Flashing a proper zip file (which contains launcher app) in custom recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your phone doesn't crash after removing the launcher, you should be fine. As long as your device comes with some kind of voice assistant, you should be able to use that to open the Play Store and then download a new launcher. You could also wait until you receive a notification from an app which will let you access the Play Store or the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask your friend to call your number. If the phone rings, half the problem is solved. You can't attend call as screen is blank.
2. When that call is disconnected and you get a black screen, pull it down and activate Bluetooth. 
   3.ask your friend to connect via Bluetooth and send a launcher apk file via bt. 
   4.install the launcher apk. And enjoy.

Comment: It gets stuck at the manufacturer logo while booting. No way it would be able to accept calls.

Answer (score 0):

the answer regarding having a friend call can work.

Its how im using my phone currently. Slightly different situation in that the proper launcher for ultra power saving mode is disabled, but after receiving a call I can wiggle my way into a few menus.

It at least gives access to calls and texts and can buy you time to find a proper solution.

Without the launcher though, i had to get a few things opened before ending the call or else it would revert to an unaccessable blank screen. My trick was pressing the "add call" button and from there could open contacts and a few other screens and menus. After that lock screen would finally reveal itself instead of blank screen